# PostgreSQL to only insert into empty columns in database

Tags: database, postgresql

I am having a tough time understanding what `NEW` and `OLD` *are*. Here is a MWE showing what I am trying to achieve. What I am trying to achieve is to prevent adding something into something else if there is already something there. Think about it like a parking spot. A new car can't go in if there is one in there already. Right now I am only checking for the first parking spot. Eventually I want to check for all three.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Parking CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Car (
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Parking (
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   spot1 INT REFERENCES Car (id),
   spot2 INT REFERENCES Car (id),
   spot3 INT REFERENCES Car (id)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_check_spot_free() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $check_spot_free$
BEGIN
   IF OLD.spot1 IS NOT NULL AND NEW.spot1 IS NOT NULL THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'spot 1 already occupied by car %. Cant change to car %', OLD.spot1, NEW.spot1;
   END IF;
   RETURN NEW;
END;

$check_spot_free$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER check_spot_free
   BEFORE UPDATE ON Parking
   FOR EACH ROW
   Execute procedure f_check_spot_free ();

INSERT INTO Car (id) VALUES (DEFAULT);
INSERT INTO Car (id) VALUES (DEFAULT);
INSERT INTO Car (id) VALUES (DEFAULT);
INSERT INTO Car (id) VALUES (DEFAULT);

INSERT INTO Parking (spot1,spot2,spot3) VALUES (NULL,NULL,4);

UPDATE Parking SET spot1=1 WHERE id=1; -- Put car 1 in spot 1
UPDATE Parking SET spot2=2 WHERE id=2; -- Put car 2 in spot 2
UPDATE Parking SET spot3=3 WHERE id=3; -- Fail while trying to put car 3 in spot 3
```

Here is the output I get

```
DROP TABLE
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE
CREATE FUNCTION
CREATE TRIGGER
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
UPDATE 1
UPDATE 0
UPDATE 0
```

I don't understand why the second and third update statements are not working. I suspect it has something to do with `NEW` and `OLD` and I just don't understand what I am doing. To make matters worse, I am not seeing an exception.

Comment: For me the 2 last `UPDATE` queries are not working because in your `Parking` table, there is **only one row**, so there is no line with `id=2` or `id=3`

Answer (score 0):

I had a flaw in my logic stemming from a lack of understanding of `OLD` and `NEW`. Turns out, `NEW` returns the entire new row, even the columns that were not updated. If anyone knows how to isolate columns which were changed, that would be a big help. In the meantime, here is how I fixed the problem, by adding the following

```
IF OLD.spot1 IS NOT NULL AND NEW.spot1 IS NOT NULL AND OLD.spot1 != NEW.spot1 THEN
```

Comment: Your `if` can be simplified to `if old.spot1 is distinct from new.spot1 then`

Comment: One way of identifying modified columns is here: http://okbob.blogspot.co.uk/2015/01/most-simply-implementation-of-history.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name at first glance, `is distinct from` does not work as it treats `null` as an existing *car*, so a new *car* can't park until the *null car* leaves first